# Dropdown navigation not working in IE10 browser but in rest its working fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-10

[Example](http://www.steelecapital.com/pages/steeleHome.aspx?spid=111025&ptype=HOME#top):

Dropdown menu is working fine in all browser but in `IE10` submenus are not visible while hovering over main menu. very strange.

Below is the js used in this [example](http://www.steelecapital.com/pages/js/IBMenu.js) :

http://www.steelecapital.com/pages/js/IBMenu.js

Dont know what was the issue but it strange.

Comment: geeting Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.steelecapital.com/pages/js/LayOut.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) http://www.steelecapital.com/pages/images/subs/

Comment: It throws the following error in IE10 aswell: `Unable to get property 'open' of undefined or null reference`(Line 290)

Comment: It doesn't work right in ie9 either. Normally Id suggest it was browser specific css you require but your using tables so that can be ruled out.  you're using a very old version of jquery 1.32 so it might be that although I've not investigated this at all.

Comment: you do a detection for absence document.all and use innerHTML otherwise you use some code presumably especially for IE. That code path throws an error. IE10 supports document.all but it should also work with the code you give other browser. If you change the faulty object detection it should work.